# How do I wait for a submit button to be clicked while I am within the Button Click Event Handler already?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

1. User submits form.
2. Form contains two password fields for validation.
3. Within SubmitButton_Click I use a do/while loop to validate.
4. If password is incorrect I would like to wait within the do loop for the submit button to be clicked again.

   ```
       // Try/Catch block looks for issues with database connection
       try
       {
           int passwordtest = 0;
           //checks that password entries are the same

           do
           {
               //*******WAIT HERE FOR SUBMIT BUTTON TO BE CLICKED AGAIN


                   if (PasswordText.Text.Equals(ReEnterPasswordText.Text))
                   {
                       MessageBox.Show("Passwords Match.");
                       passwordtest = 0;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       passwordtest = passwordtest + 1;
                       MessageBox.Show("Passwords do not match. Please try again.");
                       PasswordText.Clear();
                       ReEnterPasswordText.Clear();

                   }

           } while (passwordtest == 1);

           conDataBase.Open();
           myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
           MessageBox.Show("Saved");
           while (myReader.Read())
           {



           }
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If the passwords don't match show your message box and exit the event listener. Then when the user clicks the button again it will trigger the listener a second time and check if the passwords match again.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

As @MikeD said in the comments, you don't want to wait for a button click inside your event handler.

You also don't want to do all that database processing inside your event handler.

The problem is that there is one thread dedicated to processing all user interface activity - the UI Thread.  If you do too much processing in a UI related event handler - like a `while (myReader.Read())` loop - then you tie up the UI thread which means your application becomes unresponsive.

Your app won't be able to respond to other clicks (like on a Cancel or Close button) while it's busy in the database code.

Ideally you'll want to offload the database processing to another thread and just start that work from the Submit button handler.  Search for Responsive UI to find relevant articles like [Keep the UI thread responsive (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh994635.aspx).

You might also think about changing your UI to test the passwords earlier.  For example, you might disable the Submit button and only enable it when the contents of your two password boxes match.  That way your user can't even click on Submit until the passwords match.  The text box event handlers might be a good place to do the test and either display a mismatch error message or enable the Submit button.